# angular remember me functionality with live apis

Tags: javascript, angular

i am using localstorage to store data after user login and setting remember me key according to user selection and on window unload handler i was checking if remember me is false localstorage should be cleared. But this is working even on refreshes and the refreshes in other opened tabs.

i am new to angular, and i don't know how should i manage this remember me flow. I want the data remain preserved even if user refreshes the tab or open multiple tabs. But if remember me is not checked the user should not get any data when website is opened again in the coming future

Comment: Storage works in same browsers in multi tabs or refresh. If you open new browser it doesn’t work

Comment: yes pc_coder i know this. where to place the code to clear localstorage entirely when the user has not checked the box , when closing the browser

Comment: I think the correct way to do this is to actually not store any data unless the user has checked the box. And only if it was checked when the user logged in, actually store the data.

Comment: @MikeS. actullay i need to show the data on tab change also. I need it to be cleared on some browser close or some event if remember me check is not true.